# Rename script file in distutils

Tags: python, distutils

I have a python script, myscript.py, which I wish to install using distutils:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(..., scripts=['myscript.py'], ...)
```

I'd prefer if I could call the installed script using just `myscript` instead of typing `myscript.py`. This could be accomplished by renaming the file to just `myscript` but then a lot of editors etc. would no longer understand that it is a Python file.

Is there some way to keep the old name, `myscript.py` but still install the file as `myscript`?

Comment: How about creating a symlink `myscript -> myscript.py`?

Answer (score 14):

You might want to look at the setuptools that do this automatically for you; from
http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation :

> Packaging and installing scripts can be a bit awkward with the
>   distutils. For one thing, there’s no easy way to have a script’s
>   filename match local conventions on both Windows and POSIX platforms.
>   For another, you often have to create a separate file just for the
>   “main” script, when your actual “main” is a function in a module
>   somewhere. And even in Python 2.4, using the -m option only works for
>   actual .py files that aren’t installed in a package.
>
> setuptools fixes all of these problems by automatically generating
>   scripts for you with the correct extension, and on Windows it will
>   even create an .exe file so that users don’t have to change their
>   PATHEXT settings. The way to use this feature is to define “entry
>   points” in your setup script that indicate what function the generated
>   script should import and run. For example, to create two console
>   scripts called foo and bar, and a GUI script called baz, you might do
>   something like this:

```
setup(
    # other arguments here...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo = my_package.some_module:main_func',
            'bar = other_module:some_func',
        ],
        'gui_scripts': [
            'baz = my_package_gui:start_func',
        ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 11):

You could always do something like this (in `setup.py`):

```
import os
import shutil

if not os.path.exists('scripts'):
    os.makedirs('scripts')
shutil.copyfile('myscript.py', 'scripts/myscript')

setup(...
    scripts=['scripts/myscript'],
    ...
)
```

Comment: Using a subdirectory of `build` might be better, ie. `build/_scripts/myscript`

Answer (score 6):

This is the cleanest solution I have found so far. MFrecks answer causes problems, when creating a source distribution or executing a command other than installing.

```
import distutils.command.install_scripts
import shutil

class my_install(distutils.command.install_scripts.install_scripts):
    def run(self):
        distutils.command.install_scripts.install_scripts.run(self)
        for script in self.get_outputs():
            if script.endswith(".py"):
                shutil.move(script, script[:-3])

setup(..., cmdclass = {"install_scripts": my_install}, ...)
```

Comment: WHile this works great for `bdist`, it breaks with `bdist_rpm`. Judging by the message, it is creating `INSTALLED_FILES`, looks for those under old names, ane errors out.