# distutils setup.py for test-importable single-file script

Tags: python, distutils

My git repository looks like this:

```
setup.py
src/single_file_module_and_script.py
src/test_single_file_module_and_script.py
```

I would like, without using setuptools, to have `setup.py install` install src/single_file_module_and_script.py as an executable script named `single-file-module-and-script`.  I would prefer not to rename the .py file in the repository as I would like to keep the tests in a separate file.  The tests do `import single_file_module_and_script`.

I don't mind strongly either way if `setup.py install` installs the code as a python module also.

I would also like other distutils commands, such as python `setup.py sdist`, to work.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Note none of these answers meet the criteria in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359231/rename-script-file-in-distutils

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to avoid setuptools?

Comment: People complain about it, and it introduces complications when used with GNU stow.

Comment: I don'd know or use stow so I can't speak to that. But simply not using a superior tool simply because there are people that don't like it seems unwise.